# remote event receiver webprovisioned not firing

Tags: 2013, provider-hosted-app, remote-event-receiver

Following is my code to have webprovisioned event receiver but nothing happened, it seems it is not firing at all.

the `AppEventReceiver` file

```
EventReceiverDefinitionCreationInformation eventReceiverProvisioned = new EventReceiverDefinitionCreationInformation()
{
     EventType = EventReceiverType.WebProvisioned,
     ReceiverName = "MyRerWebProvisioned",
     ReceiverUrl = "https://temp.azurewebsites.com/Services/MyRer.svc",
     SequenceNumber = 10000,
     Synchronization = EventReceiverSynchronization.Synchronous,
     ReceiverAssembly = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().FullName,
     ReceiverClass = "MyRer"                            
};
clientContext.Site.EventReceivers.Add(eventReceiverProvisioned);
clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
```

the `MyRer.svc.cs`

```
using (ClientContext clientContext = TokenHelper.CreateRemoteEventReceiverClientContext(properties))
{
    if (clientContext != null)
    {
       if (properties.EventType == SPRemoteEventType.ItemUpdating)
       {
           var rootWeb = clientContext.Web;
           clientContext.Load(rootWeb);
           clientContext.ExecuteQuery();

           //Adding an item to a list for testing purpose
       }
    }
}
```

but nothing happened. thanks and appreciate any kind of advice.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, your Event Receiver `EventType` is `EventReceiverType.WebProvisioned` when your RER is not checking for that.

It is checking for `SPRemoteEventType.ItemUpdating`. Change the `EventType` comparison to `SPRemoteEventType.WebProvisioned`

I'd be interested to know if this `WebProvisioned` event receiver works however so let me know how you get on!